# crontab relative log path output not generated

Tags: bash, cron

`10 5 * * * rm ./rehldslog && cd ./code/rehlds && rm -rf ./build && ./build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 > ~/rehldslog 2>&1`

in the logs i can see `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)` and the command did not run as there is no build directory

what is wrong with that output syntax?

Comment: Not sure if it's significant here, but you're only redirecting the output/error streams of the last command in your chain

Comment: yes the build.sh output is what i want. but this MTA msg indicates that it wanted to email my output. i read i must use `&>` to get any output?

Comment: Wrap the whole command chain in a subshell `( ... ) > ~/rehldslog 2>&1` or command group `{ ... ; } > ~/rehldslog 2>&1`

Comment: ok now i run that command and came `rm: cannot remove './rehldslog': No such file or directory`.  does that mean that my command chain totally failed with this error?  so `rm -f rehldslog` will fix that

Comment: Crontabs use `sh` not `bash` as you've tagged. So don't break things with the `&>` you just read about.  The  `2>&1` already solved that problem anyway.

Comment: nothing is solved, there is no output logged into rehldslog until now

Answer (score 0):

my rm syntax was missing `-f`

correct:

`10 5 * * * (rm -f ./rehldslog && cd ./code/rehlds && rm -rf ./build && ./build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4) &> ~/rehldslog 2>&1`

Comment: ok `&> ~/rehldslog` did not collect the output. whats wrong. the commands all ran